# Parse values from a HTML form supported by backbone.js to json

Tags: json, backbone.js, backbone-views, backbone-routing

I am a newbie working on backbone.js
How to parse a field from a HTML form (supported by backbone.js) to the json.?

I want to develop a HTML form that is been supported by the Backbone.js .So when the Registration form is been filled it is been read in Json format...any help is really appreciated!!! thank u in advance!!

Answer (score 0):

You can transform your form in JSON with this jQuery plugin : https://github.com/maxatwork/form2js

For example if you have this elements in your form :

```
<input type="text" name="person.name.first" value="John" />
<input type="text" name="person.name.last" value="Doe" />
```

And you get the JSON with `this.$el.find('form').toObject()` you get this JSON :

```
{
  "person": {
    "name": {
      "first": "John",
      "last": "Doe"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I guess the OP wants to convert the Backbone Model into JSON not the form itself.

Comment: if it's that, you can use the `toJson()` fmethod on backbone Model

Comment: Even if this is technically correct, I would never do this in a Backbone application. Backbone Views supposed to work with models, in an ideal case there is always an underlying model to your view. You populate its properties. If required, you can convert it to JSON.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at TodoMVC: http://todomvc.com/architecture-examples/backbone/

Basically you should have an even registered on your form:

```
    events: {
        'submit form.modal-form': 'save'
    }
```

in your save function you should parse the input values and set the appropriate model properties:

```
save: function (e) {
    this.model.set('customer', $input.val().trim()); // <- parsing the form field
    console.log(this.model.toJSON()); <- model converted to JSON
}
```

Similar to your requirements: https://github.com/tastejs/todomvc/blob/gh-pages/architecture-examples/backbone/js/views/app-view.js look at `createOnEnter`.